# Looking for a function/plug-in to create sub-points in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to create points which "explode" into multiple sub-points when I click on them? I think there might be a plug-in? Can anyone help?
MortonSickels answer is almost perfect. Is is possible to attribute the sub-points to a different layer?
I have 12 points on a map (e.g. cities). When I click on a point, the point "explodes" and a number of sub-points (e.g. neighborhoods) appear. The neigbourhoods are on a different layer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question: what does "expolde into sub-points" mean? Can you add a screenshot of how the result should look like?

Comment: Those points are placed at the same location and you want to show them around when user click on them, am I correct? Check maybe Point displacement in the Layer styling.

Comment: Maybe using this answer : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342569/qgis-mouseover-actions-on-symbology to alternate between point cluster and point displacement symbology could get you something close enough....

Comment: I guess you want something similar to what Google Earth is doing? Do you want this to be able to read information on each point? if so, Point Cluster symbology gives you what you want when using "Identify Features" and clicking on a point. I agree, less cool than what GE is doing, but at least as informative. ;-)

Comment: See re-edited question

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with "attribute the sub-points to a different layer" - can you give an example?

Comment: see re-edited question

Comment: You could copy your layer with the solution by @MortenSickel and set different settings for scale based visibility

Comment: Do you want to show the subpoints in the same scale as the main map? That would probably not be too hard to write a script to do (When clicking on a point in layer A, show features in layer B that are somehow related to the clicked point). If you want to "zoom in" on the subpoints while having the rest of the map in the same scale - well, I have no idea how to do that unless you want to zoom in the entire map.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to read information on each point, what you want is already in qgis (at least the newer versions) (although, I have to agree it does not look as cool as what Google Earth is doing). Just use the normal symbology tab and set the type to Point cluster, use "Identify Results" to get the information on the points.

[image]

[image]

[image]